# JAXB different namespaces for same element unmarshall

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following example of schema xml

```xml
<a:tag xmlns:a="http://www.something.com/schema/01p00" ... >
    <a:root ... >
```

I've created the stub for this schema

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root", namespace = "http://www.something.com/schema/01p00")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root{
...
}
```

And know the schema has been updated, but the elements that are interesting me are the same. Now I have schema 2

```xml
<b:tag xmlns:b="http://www.something.com/schema/01p01" ... >
    <b:root ... >
```

In order to work with new schema, I have to change classes to:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root", namespace = "http://www.something.com/schema/01p01")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root{
...
}
```

Because I need to be backwards compatible, I want to have only one `Root` class that should be capable to work with both namespaces.

I've tried to create `package-info.java` in order to use the right namespace for each prefix, but this is not working as expected.

```java
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
namespace = "http://www.something.com/schema/01p00",
xmlns = {
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "a", namespaceURI = "http://www.something.com/schema/01p00"),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "b", namespaceURI = "http://www.something.com/schema/01p01")
},
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package schema.package;
```

How can I use the same `Root` class with these two different namespaces without duplicating all the classes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid JAXB cannot do what you want it to do (at least not in a straight forward way). An @XmlRootElement or @XmlElement can have one namespace only (or none), and it is not possible to map "the same" elements from two or more namespaces to one and the same Java class.

XML namespaces maps fairly well to Java packages, so your best bet is to have (almost) duplicate classes int two different packages, one for the "01p00" namespace and one for the "010p01" namespace.

Nothing prohibits the "interesting" classes to implement common interfaces, which would perhaps be one way to solve backwards compatibility in a convenient manner.

It might be possible to use XmlAdapters to map Root(1) and Root(2) classes to the same common Root class, so that unmarshalling works, but I cannot see how marshalling would work (turning Java classes into XML).